# How should I reference HttpClient for dnx451 and dnxcore50?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-core

How should I reference `HttpClient` using a `project.json` file?
I want both frameworks to work: `dnx451` and `dnxcore50`.

Here is my current attempt at the `project.json` file. (I've removed the irrelevant parts.)

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.29",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
}
```

Discovering the dependencies I do have listed was a trial-and-error procedure.

With this `project.json` file, the `dnxcore50` context properly resolves all the classes in this example block of code, but it fails to resolve `HttpRequestMessage`, `HttpMethod`, and `MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue` with the `dnx451` context:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "...");
request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/..."));
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
var model = await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeModel>();
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946798/httpclient-in-asp-net-5-0-not-found/27949353#27949353)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That got everything working in the dnx451 context except for the `ReadAsAsync` extension method on `HttpContent`. It is a member of the `HttpContentExtensions` class in the `System.Net.Http` namespace.  Any idea what framework assembly or dependency I need for that? This is a big help, by the way!

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov With your help I figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of the time of posting (June 11, 2015) this is the combination that worked for me for both `dnx451` and `dnxcore50`.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the reference for each frameworks? Wouldn't the top dependences apply to both framworks? I only have "System.Net.Http":"4.0.0-beta-23008" in dependencies and that shows up as both dnx451 and dnxcore50 reference in the Project List.

Comment: @jonas I just confirmed that if you do what you are saying `HttpClient` **will not** be accessible in both dnx451 and dnxcore50.  Try writing code that uses it in a project configured as you are saying.

Comment: @Timothy Shields - I have done just that except it's Microsoft.Net.HttpClient and it works fine.

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille Note the date on the question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking Timothy's answer as helpful as it lead me down the right path, but this question/answer is also a few months old. Since then, ASP.NET5 has RCed. Here's what works for me now:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.6",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which seems to be similar with this more verbose way of specifying the dependencies:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.6",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both versions do work as I was able to debug my HttpClient calls successfully.

You may ignore the other dependencies except for System.Net.Http.