# Headless Umbraco CMS with ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, umbraco, headless, headless-cms

we have an ASP .NET Core website and would like to use Umbraco. It is my understanding there is no .Net Core version of Umbraco, therefore we would need to use a headless integration. To do this, I will need to create web api's in my project, however I am not able to use Umbraco.Web.WebApi, because there is no ASP .NET Core library, so I am assuming I need to custom create my own using the standard ASP .NET Web Api. If all these assumptions are correct, I have no idea how to begin. I was curious if there are any sample .NET Core projects that show how to create the Web Api? If these assumptions are not correct, could someone please help me better understand. Thanks!!

Comment: are you just wanting to create an API for querying umbraco content? have to read this?
 https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Umbraco.Web.WebApi.UmbracoApiController` on your Umbraco project controllers, these would expose the information you need to run your Core app using a REST interface.

Then, from your Core application, you need to make REST calls to your previously created Umbraco controllers. It seems like [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891396/how-to-call-a-restful-api-with-asp-net-5#32899549) should get you on the way to making those calls.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, Umbraco 8 requires 4.7 .net Framework rather than .net core.

If you want to self-host you can extend Umbraco 8 with either [GraphQL](https://github.com/rasmusjp/umbraco-graphql) or [Head Rest](https://github.com/mattbrailsford/umbraco-headrest) Packages however these are not recently updated.

Alternatively, Umbraco offers [Heart Core](https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-heartcore/) which is cloud only headless CMS which would work. This has a reset API and soon a Graph QL.